# If $3(a+2c) =4(b+3d)$ then the equation $a x^3 + b x^2 + c x +d =0$ will have real roots in which interval?

Tags: polynomials, cubics

I tried some vales to satisfy the equality and conjectured that atleast one root will lie in the interval $[-1,0]$.  But couldn't prove. Please help

Comment: Two things to simplify working with the problem.  First, the constraint on the coefficients is homogenous, so if $(a,b,c,d)$ is an acceptable set of coefficients, then so is $(\lambda a,\lambda b, \lambda c, \lambda d)$, but this rescaling of the polynomial will not change the roots.  Therefore, if $a\neq 0$, then we can re-scale and assume that $a=1$.  Further, we can solve for $d$ in terms of the other coefficients, writing the equation in terms of b, c, and x.My suggestion is to try out different values of x and see if the equation is either obviously positive or obviously negative at any.

Comment: If $(*)$ $ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d = 0$ then, $$\begin{align} x &= \sqrt [3] {\bigg(\frac{-b^3}{27a^3} + \frac{bc}{6a^2} - \frac{d}{2a}\bigg) + \sqrt {\bigg(\frac{-b^3}{27a^3} + \frac{bc}{6a^2} - \frac{d}{2a}\bigg)^2 + \bigg(\frac{c}{3a} - \frac{b^2}{9a^2}\bigg)^2}} \\ \\ &+ \sqrt [3] {\bigg(\frac{-b^3}{27a^3} + \frac{bc}{6a^2} - \frac{d}{2a}\bigg) - \sqrt {\bigg(\frac{-b^3}{27a^3} + \frac{bc}{6a^2} - \frac{d}{2a}\bigg)^2 + \bigg(\frac{c}{3a} - \frac{b^2}{9a^2}\bigg)^2}} \ - \frac{b}{3a}\tag1\end{align}$$

Comment: $(1)$ is derived from *Scipione del Ferro*’s formula to solve for $x$ in the equation $x^3 + cx = d$. $$x^3 + cx = d$$ $$\Leftrightarrow x = \sqrt [3] {\frac d2 + \sqrt{\frac{d^2}{4} + \frac{c^3}{27}}} + \sqrt [3] {\frac d2 - \sqrt{\frac{d^2}{4} + \frac{c^3}{27}}}$$ If $(*)$ is on the condition that $3(a + 2c) = 4(b + 3d)$ then substitute into $(1)$, $$\begin{align} a &= \frac 23 (2b + 6d - 3c); \\ \\ b &= \frac 34 (a + 2c - 4d); \\ \\ c &= b + 3\bigg(d - \frac{a}{4}\bigg); \text{ and} \\ \\ d &= \frac{1}{12}(3a + 6c - 4b).\end{align}$$ This would be my only approach to prove your conjecture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $P(X)=3aX^4+4bX^3+6cX^2+12dX$.

$P(-1)=P(0)=0$ hence $P'(x)=0$ for some $x\in[-1,0]$.

Answer (score 3):

**Idea**: Replace $a\to 4a$, $b\to 3b$ and $c\to 2c$ then we get $d= a-b+c$ and consider equation

$$0 = 4ax^3+3bx^2+2cx+a-b+c$$
because of homogenity we can assume that $a=1$ so we have to consider: 
$$p(x) = 4x^3+3bx^2+2cx+1-b+c$$
Now it is enough to prove that two among $p(0)$, $p(-{1\over 2})$ and $p(-1)$ have different sign.